# Pasar parametro a Controller en Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tengo una pagina con una serie de imagenes insertadas en celdas. Tengo en mente hacer que segun que imagen pulses, te carge una pagina comun en la que dentro del controlador determine de donde viene. Para que segun de que imagen venga, haga una cosa u otra dentro de esa pagina comun.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@GetMapping(/comun/¿?¿?¿)
public String paginaComun(){
    if (?¿?parametro?¿? = "imagen1") {
       model.addAttribute("valor", "imagen1");
       return "";
    }
    else if() .......
}
```

Utilizo Thymealf por si sirve de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes mandar un parametro por la url de esta manera:

```
 @GetMapping("comun/{parametro}")
    public String paginaComun(
            @PathVariable("parametro") String parametro,
            ModelMap model) {

        /*** SELECCIONAS LA PAGINA QUE QUIERAS MOSTRAR ***/
        model.addAttribute("datos", "Estos son datos!!!");
        return "comun::" + parametro;
    }
```

Y utilizar fragmentos o la página entera:

```
return "miPaginaComun";
```

También puedes utilizar ajax. El primer ejemplo de `return comun::fragmento` recarga solo el template `comun` que contenga un `th:fragment="fragmento"`.

Para esto último ocuparias algo como `JQuery` para enviar el `POST` y cambiar a `@PostMapping`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, Me apuntare con permanente esta respuesta me sera util de aqui en adelante. Un saludo.

Comment: @Eduardo Que bien! :D